# Change color of UILabel if UITextField (in corresponding UIView) is disabled? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextfield, uilabel

I have multiple inputs that are disabled/enabled based on certain conditions — is there a way to select the adjacent `UILabel` that is in the same view?

Here's a visual the `UITextField`/`UILabel`:

[image]

Comment: Sure. Set up outlets to both the text field and the label and use those outlets to manipulate the states/colors of the text fields and labels as desired.

What part are you having a problem with?

Comment: I'm wanting to select the adjacent label of an anonymous input. Putting all labels and inputs into a collection doesn't help with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can find any views in a view with a simple loop.

```
for view in view.subviews {
    if let label = view as? UILabel {
        // do something with your view
    }
}
```

Comment: So with this solution, I'd need to know the view that the disabled input is in, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use viewWithTag option ,give specific tag to textField and fetch them

```
if let theTextField = self.view.viewWithTag(1) as? UITextField {
        print(theTextField.text)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way of identifying the adjacent label for a field. You'd have to loop through the labels looking for one in the correct position.

Instead give your text fields tags 1-10, and give your labels corresponding tags 101-110.

Then use the tag number to find the label.